# Why isn't the collapsed view button working on my navbar?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, navbar

Bootstrap provides the following code to use as a navbar. However, when I simply paste in their code without altering it, the collapsed view doesn't work. As you resize your browser window towards more narrow, the navbar turns into a button that you can click to show all the nav components again. However, it doesn't seem to be working when I simply paste in their code. Anyone know why? The nav components do get collapsed, but clicking the button to show them doesn't do anything.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
    </div>

    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Link <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <form class="navbar-form navbar-left" role="search">
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
      </form>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
```

**HTML**

```
<?php include('config/setup.php'); ?>   

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">    

    <head> 
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>Search Hound</title>

        <!--This enables the website to be mobile first-->
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

        <?php include('config/js.php'); ?>

        <?php include('config/css.php'); ?>



    </head>

    <body>

        <?php include('template/navigation.php'); ?>

        <div class="container">
         <form class="form-inline" align="center">

        <!-- Section to type question-->
            <div class="form-group" style="display:block">
                <textarea class="form-control" style="width:100%" rows="5"></textarea>
            </div>

        <!--Section to add money-->
            <div class="input-group" id="AddMoney">
              <span class="input-group-addon">$</span>
              <input id="EnterMoney" type="text" class="form-control" onkeypress='validate(event)' aria-label="Amount (in dollars and cents)">
            </div>

        <!--Section to add file-->
            <div id="AddFile">
                <a href="#" onclick="document.getElementById('uploadFile').click(); return false;">Add File</a>
                <input type="file" id="uploadFile" style="visibility: hidden;" />
            </div>

            <div id="imagePreview"></div>

        <!--Section for the Submit button-->
            <div>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
            </div>
        </form>
        </div>
        <!-- /container -->

    <div

    </body>

    <?php include('template/footer.php'); ?>

</html>
```

**config/js.php**

```
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Did you implement a javascript file as well?

Comment: Did you add `bootstrap.js` ?

Comment: Yes. I use `<?php include('config/js.php'); ?>` in the `<head>` section of my index.php and then in the `<body>` I use `<?php include('template/navigation.php'); ?>`. js.php has the CDN links to Bootstrap. navigation.php has the navbar code.

Comment: The code works fine, you are not including the bootstrap.js or jQuery correctly.

Comment: Actually, you might have hit the nail on the head. I was just messing around with another section of my site and it looked devoid of CSS/JS, even though I thought I correctly used the php include code above. I am using Aptana Studio and have made a js.php file separately to store my bootstrap CDN links. How would I link the js.php file to be used in whatever HTML document I am currently working on?

Comment: Wait actually that can't be it because the same links to bootstrap work just fine when it comes to the rest of the page! I will edit my original question to include the index.php code.

Comment: Post the code to the `config/js.php` file as well...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see that you are including jQuery before the `bootstrap.js` file. jQuery is required to use bootstrap javascript components.

Add this BEFORE `bootstrap.js` in your `config/js.php` file.

```
<!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, here is what you want:

Jquery:

```
$(".navbar-toggle").click(function(){
    $(".navbar").slideToggle();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/xz06armf/

Comment: Well, I guess I'm more trying to understand why [the navbar code taken directly from Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar) isn't working.